# Query parameter always required

Tags: c#, api, .net-core

Is there any reason why even though I didn't put BindRequired on my [FromQuery] parameter it is always returning an error please see below.

```
{
"errors": {
    "type": [
        "The type field is required."
    ]
},
"type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
"title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
"status": 400,
"traceId": "|a516ca97-4f35ffd51f30acad."
}
```

Here's the endpoint:

```
    [HttpPost("{imageId}/export", Name = nameof(ExportImage))]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Business.Realhub.Models.User), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExportImage([FromRoute] int imageId, [FromQuery] string type, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Here's my request:

```
POST /v1/images/13898656/export
```

[image]

Comment: make it optional: `string type = null`,

Comment: Make the parameter optional: `([FromRoute] int imageId, [FromQuery] string type = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)`. Note that once you assign a default value you must do the same for all arguments that proceed it.

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried adding empty string too but still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try like that? [FromQuery] string? type = null

Comment: thank you @CanÜrek. yea, I'm missing the ? on string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify your code as below. This is modified by adding in an optional prameter for `type`

```
[HttpPost("{imageId}/export", Name = nameof(ExportImage))]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Business.Realhub.Models.User), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExportImage(
    [FromRoute] int imageId, 
    CancellationToken cancellationToken, 
    [FromQuery] string? type = null)
{
    //Controller code
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Thank you mate! you save me!